# Angular coordinates of catia product

Tags: vba, catia

through bello script I achieve the position of selected product in Catia.

```vb
Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim selection1 As Selection
Set selection1 = productDocument1.Selection

selection1.Search "CATElectricalSearch.MultipleSegments,all"

Dim product1 As Product

Set product1 = selection1.Item(1).Value
'msgbox "product Name = " & product1.Name

Dim pos(11)
    
Set Dokument = product1    ' assigining selection part to get coordinates
        
ddd = Dokument.Name
Dokument.Position.GetComponents pos   'getting coordinates
ccc = "Origin Point: X= " & pos(9) & " Y= " & pos(10) & " Z= " & pos(11)
```

Through above code I can get only get position coordinates.
Now I want to get Angle coordinates of same selection.
can anyone help me on this

Comment: Do you need the orientation of the product or the coordinates in an spherical coordinate system?

Comment: i am looking for orientation.

Comment: So have a closer look into the first 9 values of the array you get from _GetComponents_ (component 0 to 2: x-axis; 3 to 5: y-axis; 6 to 8: z-axis)

Comment: i am getting some values through this (msgbox "Origin Angle: X= " & pos(0) & " Y= " & pos(2) & " Z= " & pos(3)). but not matching with ordination or angular values

Comment: These values describe three vectors: for each axis one vector. You have to calculate the angels yourself.

Comment: @MeghaP Stop tagging with [tag:vbscript]  this is [tag:vba]. There is a difference.